# c# Joining Strings for Email Body

Tags: c#, string, join, newline

I dont know whats happening here but I cant join two strings together with a newline between them. I use the following code in my Windows Store App to open the email client and prefill an email:

```
String recipient = "me@here.com";
String Bodymsg = "Line One" + Environment.NewLine + "Line Two";
String SubLine = "Report Fault";
String BodyText = "mailto:?to=" + recipient + "&subject=" + SubLine + "&body=" + Bodymsg;
var mailto = new Uri(BodyText);
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

This works fine but the body comes out like this.

```
Line OneLineTwo
```

What I want to get is

```
Line One  
Line Two
```

I have tried using `"/r/n"` and `"/n"` instead of `Environment.NewLine` but it gives the same effect. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I would recommend using stringbuilder for this. It will be cleaner, but more importantly it will deliver better performance. An example of stringbuilder for this would be: 

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendLine("This will be a full line");
    builder.Append("this will be started at the end of the last string which in this case is the beginning of a new line")
    .AppendLine("You can also use the fluent format to improve readability");

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Guys Didnt think of searching for Mailto questions rather than string questions the following works   String Bodymsg = "Line One" + "%0D%0A" + "Line Two";

Answer (score 0):

The newline character is `\n` and not `/n`, have you tried:

`String Bodymsg = "Line One\nLine Two";`

Comment: If that were the problem, then `Environment.NewLine` would have worked just fine.

Comment: Hi Sorry that didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code and how you're using the email, I'd say it might be formatted in HTML.  Try concatenating the two strings with a `<BR>`.

Comment: That is my full code I click a button and it runs the code above which opens windows 8 email program and composes the email. The problem is in the message body where whatever I try I cant get it to drop lines